# How to add string object's value into JS regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var foo = "blaa";
var regex = /foo/i;
```

results in `/foo/i` instead of `/blaa/i`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/User:Potappo/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp_(constructor)) constructor:

```
var regex = new RegExp(foo, 'i');
```

It takes two arguments, the first expect a string that represents the regular expression pattern and in the second optional argument you can define the regular expression flags you want.